# Canvas performance - long time of clearRect execution

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, fabricjs

I have problem with canvas performance. At simplest operations I have 3-5 FPS and application is useless. It happens in every browser even when I have one object in canvas. Before last Chrome update application worked better but only on this browser.

On image you can see performance log from Google Chrome which is recorded when I move object by mouse and canvas has 4 objects but it happens with single object too. In `step_2.onMouseMove` is method which set object position based on pointer coords (very simple calculations)

I use fabric.js library in this project. What could be the reason? How to boost performance of this?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

[image: Performance log (Chrome)]

Comment: Ok I made some edits and that's all because I can't find more details which may be useful.

Comment: You will need to provide a example @Damian

Comment: Looking at the green composite (DOM controlled compositing) of about 80ms (Very long) your problem is related to having a canvas that is way to large, and/or page content that is over the amount of memory that can easily be handled but the GPU. A clearRect should perform in under 1-2ms if the resolution is near screen res and you have Hardware accelerated graphics on.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks! I had canvas 3000x3000 (I must have big, project specification) but after change to 2000x2000 all works great!

Comment: BTW I see you are calling `renderAll` from inside the mouse move event. This is very bad for performance (and user/mouse interaction). Use requestAnimationFrame to schedule redraws, and only use the mouse events to record the current mouse state, DONT render from IO events.

Comment: can you give fabricjs version using? request animation frame is coming anyway. but 3fps will stay 3fps if the performance are bad. what are your project specifications? i can give a detailed answer on approaches

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I use Fabric 1.7.0. Project is huge because it's a designing of room with furniture and addons so it need big canvas if user want to create big room. Canvas size should be minimum 2000px because then room wall can have 10m max.

Comment: cant you work  on a screen size canvas and use zoom and pan? you can get virtually unlimited size and 60fps